# How should library forks be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

#### Some background on a specific case:

The popular [Discord API wrapper](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py) for hosting Discord bots using Python has been [recently announced](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/4a2f62751b9600a31a0d3c78100287f1) to be discontinued with no further developments be made to the library. Since discord.py is an API wrapper, and without constant updates, new features doesn't get implemented and compliance with the API begins to break. So users of discord.py would have to look for alternatives—most went looking for forks of the library.

Currently, there're many new prominent forks of the library, each guarantees to be compatible with the existing wrapper to make transition simpler. To name a few with their GitHub stars and (searchable) SO posts:

- [Pycord](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord) (645 stars) ([2 SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22pycord%22+is%3Aquestion))
- [disnake](https://github.com/EQUENOS/disnake) (176 stars)
- [nextcord](https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord) (372 stars) ([4 SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22nextcord%22+is%3Aquestion))
- [enhanced-discord.py](https://github.com/iDevision/enhanced-discord.py) (182 stars)
- [novus](https://github.com/Voxel-Fox-Ltd/Novus) (44 stars) ([1 SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22novus%22+is%3Aquestion+%5Bdiscord.py%5D))
- And many more...

Although not many posts mentions which library they use, persumably many still uses discord.py since it *still works*, but the issue is when it stops working, people will have to transition to one of the forks or a different library altogether (none exists yet).

So far, I see three scenarios of users tagging these library:

1. [discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord) and mentions in the post that they're using X library. Incorrect because [discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord) is for tagging Discord API specific problems, and shouldn't be used for support on a particular library's syntaxes.
2. [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py) and mentions in the post that they're using X library. Incorrect because some fork features aren't available / have different syntaxes than discord.py.
3. [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py) or [discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord) but doesn't mention the library at all. Incorrect because it leads to confusion and miscommunication between the questioner and answerer, with OP usually mentions the fork in the comments (a major time waste!).

None of them are preferred solutions. And as time goes on, the issue thickens as the forks will be more and more different from the parent discord.py and from each other.

**Update:**

Given that the top-voted (accepted) answer suggests to create new tags for questions that are specific about the fork, I created some tags for questions that I see fit (and tagged a few posts). This should allow newer users to use these tags to tag their questions in the future ([pycord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pycord), [nextcord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nextcord)).

---

#### Now finally my question:

How to tag posts when a library becomes discontinued and branches into multiple forks?

I see two solutions:

- Introduce new tags for each of the forks. But the issue with this is that many current questions are not fork-specific, they're actually still asking about features in the parent library—which can lead to duplicate questions. And since these forks are new, some might *die out* before it becomes popular.
- Do nothing *yet*. Wait for the right moment to introduce the tags. But when *is* the right moment? And how should they be tagged/titled right now given that the fork and parent library may be different in some aspects?

Comment: Won't this just solve itself? Presumably people that are still using Discord.Py will tag that, and if someone is using a new fork, they'll tag that. People can still be directed to questions for the original library, if it's applicable.

Comment: Is experts in "Foo" can answer questions about "FooFork" without needing specific "FooFork" knowledge, then the question is not really about  "FooFork", and there is no need to create a new tag.

Comment: @Larnu Sadly our [average question-askers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/discord.py/topusers) on the topic doesn't have the reps to do so, would you suggest that I edit and add the new fork tags to questions when I deem it needs a specific tag for the fork—based on if the question is specific to "FooFork" as opposed to "Foo" (from yivi's analogy)?

Comment: If the question is about a specific fork, and the OP doesn't have the rep to create said tag, then yes by all means add the relevant tag, @Taku .

Comment: We should get [@Rapptz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1381108/) over here. He's the maker of the library.

Comment: But anyway, since there's [literally 2.9 forks](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/network/members), out of which maybe 100 are actively maintained, a tag for each would still be way too much. Besides, pretty much all of the forks have their own Discord server where they can get help in.

Comment: If the library's dead, you'd probably hang the tag from its big toe...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, I don't think we need to do anything; very likely this isn't a problem and tags will encompass the new forks as, when and *if* they need to.

As you've mentioned the majority of questions are still about [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py) right now, so tagging them with said tag is the correct course of action.

If the OP is using a specific fork, it's very likely (especially at the moment) that the vast majority of the functionality is still based on discord.py, so very likely tagging [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py) is *still* the correct tag. Although, yes, the OP could be using a fork it's a fork of discord.py and the functionality they are using is from the original library, not the fork; it actually therefore makes little sense to not tag [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py).

As for questions that are *specifically* about functionality that is in a fork and *not* in discord.py then should the question be tagged with the new fork (for example [pycord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pycord)). If the user asking the question doesn't have the reputation to create said tag, then by all means add the tag as an edit yourself if you have suitable reputation. If they've (incorrectly) tagged [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py) then remove that tag as well, as the functionality doesn't exist in said library.

Conversely, if after some tags have started appearing you see a question tagged with a fork, but isn't about that specific fork and instead is actually about the core library, discord.py, you should likely be editing the tags to add [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py). It likely doesn't do any harm to leave the fork's tag, but adding [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py) gives the question exposure to experts on discord.py that don't follow that specific fork.